# QGIS Get maximum sum of a feature subset in Atlas-View

Tags: qgis, expression, atlas, summarizing, subset

I have a data-layer called `data` wich looks like this:

[image]

I also have an atlas-layout with pagenames defined by the column `Jahr` from the another Layer, representing the unique values from the `Data`-Layer.

In the atlas-layout I have a text-field, which shall contain the following, build up by an expression: the maximum of all sums from the column `Anzahl`, grouped by `Datum`, on each atlas-page.

So the feature-subset for each atlas-page would be all `Datum`-fields where `Jahr`= `atlas_pagename`. From this subset the maximum sum of `Anzahl`shall be displayed.

For Exmaple on the atlas-page `2014` the result would be "165"( the sum of all values from the column `Anzahl` from the `Datum` 2014-10-01, which is the highest result in this example for 2014).

I already tried the expression `sum("Anzahl", group_by:="Datum")`, which works well in the field calculator, but I cannot manage to access the `Data`-Layer from the expression-builder in the atlas-view.

Comment: What about a joint between the 2 layer? and then display the table from your atlas layer?